# Apache .htaccess hotlinking redirect

Tags: apache, image, .htaccess, redirect, hotlinking

I am trying to create a redirection when someone hotlinks images in one directory on my site.  If someone hotlinks an image, I want to redirect them to a corresponding image (same file name) in a different directory.

If someone hotlinks:

> www.mydomaoin.com/PlayImages/Basic/Embedded/{ImageName.gif}

I want it to redirect to:

> www.mydomaoin.com/PlayImages/Basic/Shared/{ImageName.gif}

Thoughts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine on

#redirect image hotlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?mydomain.com/?.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/Embedded/(.*jpg|.*gif|.*png)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %{HTTP_HOST}/%1/Shared/%2 [R=302,L]
```

If the referrer is not blank, and the referrer is not equal to your own domain, and the request is for a resource in the /Embedded folder ending in jpg/gif/png, then rewrite the url to replace /Embedded with /Shared

You may want to change the `[R=302]` to a different [code](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3) to suit your needs.

Comment: It is obviously doing something, since images from that directory is not linking a file, I'm getting a broken link (Red X).  Is there a way to output to a file for debugging?

Comment: I looked at the Apache logs, and it appears that it is attempting to access MyDomain.com/{filename.gis}/Shared/

Comment: Had a minor typo in the RewriteRule, fixed it.  Checking the code on my server now to be sure.

Comment: Sorry about that, I should have tested the code before posting it. There was the aforementioned typo in RewriteRule, and I used REQUEST_FILENAME in the RewriteCond when I meant to use REQUEST_URI.  It tests fine now :)