# Need help on setting up htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, web, shared-hosting

I have a website. Some of the images on my website are hotlinked in other websites. I would like to block them. I would like to allow some sites to hotlink my images (like some forums), as I have made posts about my product in those forums. I have list of sites which I regularly promote my products and I would like to allow them to hotlink my images. I would like to block all other sites other than my list.

I use shared hosting from hostgator btw.

I hope it is clearly understandable.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! This question has already been asked and found good answers. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=prevent+hotlinking

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache .htaccess hotlinking redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126552/apache-htaccess-hotlinking-redirect)

Comment: my requirement is different. I would like to allow some sites to hot link my images/files and not allow others. thanks

Comment: ah, sorry. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yoursite\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://.*$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|gif|bmp|png)$ /media/nohotlinks.png [L]
```

Please read this article for more information
http://www.yourhtmlsource.com/sitemanagement/bandwidththeft.html

Comment: my requirement is different. I would like to allow some sites to hot link my images/files and not allow others. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Add the sites you want to allow as RewriteCondition to the hotlinking rule of your choice, e.g. @YNhat's above.

For hotlinking from `alloweddomain.com`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?alloweddomain\.com
```