# Disable hot linking or direct download of my videos and only stream the video when it's displayed from a page in my website

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, download, hotlinking

I want to disbale hot linking of `FLV` and `MP4` videos hosted on my server, except when the videos are displayed from a page which its URL *starts with* :
`http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?main_page=videos_page&` 
What are the apache configurations that I have to add to my .htaccess file?

Comment: This is near duplicate of [Apache .htaccess hotlinking redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1126552/331508) and several others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable hot-linking and replace the content with a generic site logo fo sorts to direct people back to your site rather then the image, add this to the .htaccess folde rin the root of your site:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yoursite\.com/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !hotlink\.(gif|png\SOME FILETYPES NOT TO HOTLINK) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.php?main_page=videos_page&
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.mywebsite.org/generic/imagetoreplace.png [NC]
```

Remember, .htaccess is hidden, so make sure 'show hidden files' it turned on in yoru ftp client.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think you didn't read my question well enough.

Comment: Maybe you could elaborate. Your questional was disabling hotlinking on videos. Just change gif|png to mon|avi|mp4|flv... etc. Then just add a rewrite condition for that url. Easy. What am I not getting here?

Comment: I said in my question "except when the videos are displayed from a page which its URL starts with : http://www.mywebsite.com/index.php?main_page=videos_page&. you didn't mention anything answering that.

Comment: `HTTP_REFERER` can be easily faked